# How to "read_some" from Actionscript 3 tcp socket?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

So I look at as3 [socket api](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) and see `readBytes(bytes:ByteArray, offset:uint = 0, length:uint = 0):void` but how to implement "read some" (provide ByteArray and desired length of bytes to be read and get from function real ammount of read data `<=` provided length)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bytesAvailable property to determine if you can read "desiredLength" bytes http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#bytesAvailable

```
var desiredLength:Number = 20;

desiredLength = Math.min(desiredLength,myByteArray.bytesAvailable);
mySocket.readBytes(myByteArray, 0, desiredLength);
```